# ReduceRight with Reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to implement reduceRight.

I was wondering if I can use my reduce inside reduce right. I did most part of it, but I'm getting an error for some test cases.

My code:

**MyReduce:**

```
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(cb, initialVal) {
    if(!cb)
        throw new Error("No CB defined");

    var accumulator = (initialVal === undefined) ? undefined : initialVal;

    for(var i= 0; i<this.length; i++){
        if(accumulator !== undefined) {
            accumulator = cb.call(undefined, accumulator, this[i], i, this)
        } else {
            accumulator = this[i];
        }
    }

    return accumulator;
}
```

**My Reduce Right (with myReduce)**

```
Array.prototype.myReduceRight2 = function(cb, initialVal) {
    if(!cb)
        throw new Error("No CB defined");

    this.reverse();

        const res = this.myReduce((acc,val) => {
        return acc.concat(val);
    });

    return res;
}
```

When I run the method:

```
const reduceRight2 = test2.myReduceRight2((acc, val) => {
    return acc.concat(val);
}, []);
```

For test cases:

```
const test1 = [1, 20, 30, 80, 2, 9, 3];
const test2 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
```

**Test2 passes but test1 fails :(**

Can someone enlighten where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `myReduceRight2` you don't pass the `initialVal` to the `myReduce` method.

In addition reduce and reduceRight don't change original arrays, so you should always clone the original array before applying making changes (reverse for example).

```js
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(cb, initialVal) {
  if (!cb)
    throw new Error("No CB defined");

  let [accumulator, ...arr] = initialVal === undefined ? [...this] : [initialVal, ...this];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    accumulator = cb.call(undefined, accumulator, arr[i], i, arr);
  }

  return accumulator;
}

Array.prototype.myReduceRight2 = function(cb, initialVal) {
  if (!cb)
    throw new Error("No CB defined");

  const arr = [...this].reverse(); // don't reverse the original array

  const res = arr.myReduce(cb, initialVal); // pass initialVal

  return res;
}

const test1 = [1, 20, 30, 80, 2, 9, 3];
const test2 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];

const test1R = test1.myReduceRight2((acc, val) => {
    return acc.concat(val);
}, []);

const test2R = test2.myReduceRight2((acc, val) => {
    return acc.concat(val);
}, []);

console.log(test1R);
console.log(test2R);
```

Comment: Q: can we do it without reversing the array? I heard one of my friend saying that it's possible to do it without reversing the array.

`const arr = [...this].reverse() //without this`

Comment: If you want to use `myReduce` (or reduce) you'll have to reverse the array, but you can implement `myReduce` with a for loop that iterates backwards.

Comment: But that would change the implementation for myReduce? (It wouldn't work for regular case(s)) .. Trying to see if i can change something instead of reversing an array that would let me do reduceRight

Comment: Sorry. I meant implement `myReduceRight2` with a for loop that iterates backwards instead of using `myReduce`.

Comment: Yeah but is there anyway i can use myReduce and still not use reverse? i.e travel array only once?

Comment: Might be, but don't have any idea.